# Is there a way to make the input as speech to text with Python speech recognition by using voice to answer the questions

Tags: python, math, speech-recognition, voice

I'm trying to create a math quiz by using speech to the text input to answer the questions currently this is what I got is there a way for me to use my speech to answer the questions?

```
import random


score=0

for question_num in range(1, 5):
    ops = ['+', '-', '*']
    rand=random.randint(1,10)
    rand2=random.randint(1,10)
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
    print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
    print ("The question is",rand,operation,rand2)

    ans=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
    if ans==maths:
        print ("Correct")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect. The actual answer ",maths)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some options here:

1. [Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech)
2. [Sphinx OSS Speech Recognition Toolkit](https://cmusphinx.github.io/)
3. [Wit.ai NLP API](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart)
4. [Houndify Speech Recognition API](https://pypi.org/project/Houndify/)
5. [Azure Cognitive Speech Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/speech-services/)

[This](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) library provides an example that wraps over most of these APIs [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py). You can try to apply this to your usecase.